# Is it correct to create a shader program for camera?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, 3d, webgl, model-view

I want to create a separate class/prototype for camera object in my 3D application.

There is a `Model-View` matrix as I understood, which is used by developer for translating/rotating/using other Affine transformations for any 3D-object, which is added to scene.

But, my camera isn't a thing like some mesh. `Camera` doesn't need to have a color, so fragment shader is not needed (of course, if you don't want to visualize a camera as `LINES`, and switch between different cameras, just for example), so what do I really need for camera?

- position in 3-dimensional vector ( x, y, z )
- mat4 matrix, which describes position and some additional vector components, which I will use in vertex shader, and which will be used for camera's position translate
- some controls for moving camera ( I don't want to describe big details about it, but just for example, let's say we will use only keyboard keys for moving and rotating it)

So, my question is... If viewport of our 3D-scene is represented by `Model-View` matrix on which any object is being processed by some Affine transformation. Is it correct to create a particular shader program for the camera object or maybe it's more correct to define such a shader program for scene object and just in some `draw` method/function translate camera position to `Model-View` matrix, which is hold in the property of `Scene` object?

I'm using WebGL library for my project, but I think some `OpenGL` developers may also answer to such a question, because these things are similar in both libraries.

Comment: None of that sounds like things you can't do with the in built glTranslate and glRotate. Is there some special reason you would want to do your camera inside your shader as opposed to in your program (not familiar with webgl, is it java or javascript?)

Comment: @newObjekt it's JavaScript

Comment: @newObjekt there are not any affine math functions in WebGL like rotate or translate, for such aims, who is using WebGL/JavaScript use mat4 library or implement those math functions manually. But it doesn't relate to question. For example, I can use C++ and OpenGL and not WebGL with JavaScript. As I remember OpenGL doesn't provide a camera object without additional libraries too (if you use plain API without any additional stuff), so if you are using such a way, you must define a class for Camera object in C++ as I suppose. Am I right?

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Well then a good way to do it would to just put 2 uniform vec4s in your vertex shader. One for your look vector and a second for your world space coordinate and apply them to your modelviewprojection. That would be essentially the same result as glRotate/glTranslate.

Comment: A single GLSL program, no. You usually apply your camera transformation in every GLSL program you use. So your vertex shader will look similar for everything. Ordinarily I would strongly suggest you use Uniform Buffer Objects to simplify the design of those vertex shaders (e.g. bind your camera matrices once and use them in every shader), but you are using WebGL so that's not a possibility.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but [this might help](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-camera.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to create a particular shader program for the camera object

No, because *there is no camera* in OpenGL. In fact *there is not even a scene* in OpenGL. OpenGL is a very simplicistic drawing API. All that OpenGL does is drawing points, lines or triangles to a pixel framebuffer, one point, line or triangle at a time and once it's drawn OpenGL already forgot about it.

Shaders are little programs that control how points, lines or triangles are turned into pixels on the screen. Shaders do not "control" scene objects. Why? Because there's no scene in OpenGL and there are no scene objects in OpenGL.

There is no camera. What you could think of a camera (but isn't) is some sub-transformation in the modelview that's moving the geometry on the screen around in a way, as if it were the result of moving a camera.

Note that this applies equally to WebGL and OpenGL-ES.